# Volume generated by a revolving region (not the $x$ or $y$ axis)

Tags: calculus

I am not getting the answer in the book in the following problem: Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region between the $x$ axis and the parabola $y=4x-x^2$ about the line $y=6$. I calculated $\pi x$ integral from $0$ to $4$ of $(4x-x^2-6)^2 dx$ but my answer is $\frac{752\pi}{15}$ and the book‘s answer is 
$\frac{1408\pi}{15}$. Is my set up even correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually found the wrong volume, but, believe it or not, you're almost there. You need to subtract the volume that you get from the volume of the cylinder of radius $6$ and height $4$: $\pi\cdot 6^2\cdot 4=144\pi$:

$$
V=144\pi-\pi\int_{0}^{4}[6-(4x-x^2)]^2\,dx=
144\pi-\frac{752\pi}{15}=\\
\frac{2160-752}{15}\pi=\frac{1408\pi}{15}\ cubic\ units.
$$

[Wolfram Alpha check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=144%20*%20pi%20-%20pi%20*%20integrate%20(6-(4*x-x%5E2))%5E2%20dx%20from%200%20to%204).

If you want the whole thing to be written as a single integral, write it like this (we're using the washer method):

$$
V=\pi\int_{0}^{4}\left(6^2-[6-(4x-x^2)]^2\right)\,dx.
$$

Answer (score 1):

A vertical slice through the solid of revolution will be an annulus with outer radius $R=6$ and inner radius $r=6-(4x-x^2)$ on the interval $[0,4]$. So the volume will be given by

$$ V=\int_0^4\pi(R^2-r^2)\thinspace dx $$
[image: Solid of revolution]

Answer (score 0):

Simply shift the parabola downwards so that $y=6$ becomes the $x$-axis, by replacing $y$ with $y+6$. You now need to find the volume of solid of revolution of $y=-6+4x-x^2$ around the $x$ axis, which is done in the usual way.